# How do I change automatic mounts of removable vfat / fat32 drives/partitions to use "noexec"?

Tags: mount, vfat, udisks

When I plug in a USB drive it is automatically mounted on `/run/media/user/fslabel`.  This is done, I guess by some udev/dbus/thunar/nautilus/gvfs or other system, and I find this convenient and do not want to revert to manual mounting by root.  However, I have a problem with the default mount options: vfat drives are mounted such that the **executable flag ist set on all regular files**. This is a nuissance and a security problem and I wish to disable it.

*How do I set system-wide options for mounting, like using the `noexec` flag for **all** `vfat` partitions and disabling mounting of `ext4` partitions by user-space programs/daemons?*

A few years ago I tried something very time-consuming on a different system, like editing some `udev` or `dbus` rules (quite apparently not files designed to be edited by hand), which was a great effort due to lack of proper documentation and great variation between distros.  Is this the intended and only way?  If so, could someone please tell me what to change where?

I am using Arch Linux, CentOS and openSUSE with the XFCE Desktop.  Automount may be performed by one of nautilus, thunar or dolphin, running in the background (or possibly, a service started by these?!).  I am not sure because it happens in the background.

Comment: On what unix variant/distribution? What desktop environment do you use? Do note that setting the executable flag is *not* a security problem except in extremely rare scenarios with restricted accounts or strange configurations that would somehow automatically execute executable files, but not read readable files, on removable media.

Comment: Thanks @Gilles - I mostly use Arch Linux with XFCE, but also openSUSE and CentOS.  I run instances of nautilus and/or dolphin and/or thunar just to use their automount function (I am not patient enough to copy or open files using these programs as navigation is so slow).  Potential security problems arise due to `rsync`ing / `cp -p`ing files to my own filesystem so that suddenly I have thousands of executable files which may even be writable to group/others (again due to mount options I did not set).  I do consider this a security risk - but then this question was no question on security.

Comment: The [Arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Mount#VFAT.2C_FAT.2C_DOS) suggests that when a partition of type VFAT is mounted the `/usr/bin/mount.vfat` script is executed. By the looks of it, you could manually edit that file to add whichever options you like.

Comment: Thanks @Bridgey , but I think that would have consequences on manual mounting (as root) of these drives.  It's probably better to configure the calling process.

Comment: @don_crissti Thanks, I think you are on to something.  Indeed a `/usr/lib/udisks2/udisksd` is running as `root`. This in turn is apparently automatically started by `dbus-daemon`.  I am pretty sure one of them can be configured (e.g. with entries in `/lib/udev/rules.d/`, I think that is what I did last time -- `/lib/udev/rules.d/80-udisks.rules`?). https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Udisks also has some hints, and I will dig deeper - unless someone knows the next steps?  - - - -  As to the second question, no, I meant external ext[34] and LUKS partitions (the user gets a password prompt?!).

Comment: @don_crissti I looked, and so probably options for vfat mounting cannot be given. I think one may be able to disallow mounting by type, though, by the looks of the rules?! When I insert a USB (3.0) thumbdrive or HDD all ext[34] partitions get mounted (I wish they weren't) and the user gets a graphical prompt for any LUKS partition to unlock. I wish to disable both. A user may have FAT drives but others may only be mounted by root. The password/phrase prompt is simply a nuissance, even if the user cannot guess the correct password, anyway. The prompt itself, I do realise, comes from some tool.

Comment: @don_crissti Do you want to turn this into a nice answer so that I can give you the bounty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

External media/drives mounting is handled by `udisks2` on most modern distros. I don't think there's any trivial way to change the default mount options as they are hard-coded (see `FSMountOptions` in [`udiskslinuxfilesystem.c`](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/udisks/tree/src/udiskslinuxfilesystem.c?id=aa02e5fc53efdeaf66047d2ad437ed543178965b)) that is, they're not configurable (at least not yet<sup>1</sup>). Your options are quite limited: unmount the partition and remount it with different mount options (unless you're willing to patch the source code or write your own automount tool).

As to your other question:

> I think one may be able to disallow mounting by type, though, by the
>   looks of the rules?! When I insert a USB (3.0) thumbdrive or HDD all
>   ext[34] partitions get mounted (I wish they weren't) and the user gets
>   a graphical prompt for any LUKS partition to unlock. I wish to disable
>   both. A user may have FAT drives but others may only be mounted by
>   root.

You could use a `udev` rule to ignore all USB thumbdrive partitions except `vfat` ones. Create a new rule file e.g. `/usr/lib/udev/rules.d/90-ignore-nonvfat.rules` with the following content:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="block", ENV{DEVTYPE}=="partition", ENV{ID_BUS}=="usb", ENV{ID_FS_TYPE}!="vfat", ENV{UDISKS_IGNORE}="1"
```

(replace `UDISKS_IGNORE` with `UDISKS_PRESENTATION_HIDE` if your distro uses udisks1).

<sup>1: see [FreeDesktop ML](http://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/devkit-devel/2015-April/001668.html) for a proposed patch (and a long discussion).</sup>