# Setting default udisk2 NTFS option for removable drive

Tags: debian, ntfs-3g, udisks

I am running [debian/jessie](https://www.debian.org/releases/stable/) amd64, and I would like to change the default options for `ntfs-3g`. Namely I'd like to state that any removable device for which filesystem is NTFS, should be mounted with `windows_names` option (see [doc](http://www.tuxera.com/community/ntfs-3g-manual/#4)).

I am running a GNOME desktop environement and as per my understanding it is delegating mounting to [udisks2](https://packages.qa.debian.org/u/udisks2.html).

Comment: You can't change those options as they're [hard-coded.](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/209546)